# IndexError: index out of range in self error while running a pre trained bart model for text summarization

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization, bart

I have the following pipeline for text summarization from a pertained bart model:

`summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="philschmid/bart-large-cnn-samsum")`

but I get the following error when I try longer documents:

`"IndexError: index out of range in self error "`

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks